How to set Tab index for control in the Form
In Power Apps, I have a Form that contains three columns: UserID, UserName, and Email. I want to move the Email column to the first position. However, after manually dragging Email to the first column, I find that when I press the Tab key, Email is still selected third.
I know we can change TabIndex property in old version. but with Modern Control, there's no TabIndex property anymore. How can I adjust the order of Tab? thanks.

According to microsoft.learn: 'If the navigation order is unexpected, you should first check if the app structure is logical'. Check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/accessible-apps-structure#logical-keyboard-navigation-order

Try improved canvas keyboard navigation , there is Advanced configuration with mixed settings, check it  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/accessibility-keyboard-navigation

okay, but that is an experimental feature, not suitable mostly for production environment :)
